# Strapi dockerize with docker-compose complete guide

Tags: docker, docker-compose, strapi

https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/installation/docker.html#creating-a-strapi-project
dockerize strapi with docker and dockercompose
Resolve different error

###### strapi failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Answer (score 1):

you can use my dockerized project.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16.15-alpine3.14
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app
WORKDIR /opt/app
RUN adduser -S app
COPY app/ .
RUN npm install
RUN npm install --save @strapi/strapi
RUN chown -R app /opt/app
USER app
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 1337
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

if you don't use `RUN npm run build` your project on port 80 or `http://localhost` work but strapi admin templates call `http://localhost:1337` on your system that you are running on `http://localhost` and there is no `http://localhost:1337` stabile url and strapi throw exceptions like:

```
Refused to connect to 'http://localhost:1337/admin/init' because it violates the document's Content Security Policy.
```

```
Refused to connect to 'http://localhost:1337/admin/init' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' https:".
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  #Strapi Service (APP Service)
  strapi_app:
    build:
      context: .
    depends_on:
      - strapi_db
    ports:
      - "80:1337"
    environment:
      - DATABASE_CLIENT=postgres
      - DATABASE_HOST=strapi_db
      - DATABASE_PORT=5432
      - DATABASE_NAME=strapi_db
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=strapi_db
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=strapi_db
      - DATABASE_SSL=false
    volumes:
    - /var/scrapi/public/uploads:/opt/app/public/uploads
    - /var/scrapi/public:/opt/app/public
    networks:
      - app-network

  #PostgreSQL Service
  strapi_db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: strapi_db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: strapi_db
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: strapi_db
      POSTGRES_DB: strapi_db
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

in docker compose file I used postgres as database, you can use any other databases and set its config in app service environment variables like:

```
environment:
      - DATABASE_CLIENT=postgres
      - DATABASE_HOST=strapi_db
      - DATABASE_PORT=5432
      - DATABASE_NAME=strapi_db
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=strapi_db
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=strapi_db
      - DATABASE_SSL=false
```

for using environment variables in project you must use `process.env` for getting operating system environment variables.

change `app/config/database.js` file to:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  connection: {
    client: process.env.DATABASE_CLIENT,
    connection: {
      host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
      port: parseInt(process.env.DATABASE_PORT),
      database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
      user: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
      // ssl: Boolean(process.env.DATABASE_SSL),
      ssl: false,
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: That docker build ends in `ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration`

Answer (score 0):

#### Dockerize Strapi with Docker-compose

```
FROM node:16.14.2

# Set up the working directory that will be used to copy files/directories below :
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json to root directory inside Docker container of Strapi app
COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 1337

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

#docker-compose file

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  strapi:
container_name: strapi
restart: unless-stopped
build:
  context: ./strapi
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
volumes:
  - strapi:/app
  - /app/node_modules
ports:
  - '1337:1337'

volumes:
  strapi:
    driver: local
```